# React Redux: refresh API data on locale change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am using redux to fetch my multilingual website's content from my API.

Also, i am storing the language selected in redux:

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleLocaleChange = event => {
        const selectedLocale = event.target.value

        dispatch(changeLocale(selectedLocale))
    };
```

```
const {reducer, actions} = createSlice({
    name: 'i18n',
    initialState: {
        locale: Locale.EN
    },
    reducers: {
        changeLocale: (state, action: PayloadAction<Locale>) => {
            state.locale = action.payload
        }
    }
})
```

My question is, how can I rerender the components that depends on server state based on the locale selected?

Right now i am using `useEffect` with the locale as a dependency:

```
    const locale = useSelector(state => state.i18n.locale);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchTrips(locale));
    }, [locale]);
```

Although this is not very effective to do in every component that depends on server state as the app scales.
How can i have a global solution for this?

What I have tried is to wrap all my components in a component, although when the locale changes the children components do not rerender.

```
    const locale = useSelector(getLocale)

    const [localeState, setLocale] = useState(locale)

    const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
        setLocale(locale)
    }, [locale])

    let render = 0
    console.log("Localizer", render++)

    return props.children
}
```

Comment: Why is it not effective?  If it feels like too much boilerplate, you could wrap it up in a custom hook named something like `useLocale()`?

Comment: It looks like HOC can come to help to share you stateful in this case? Do you know that?

Comment: @tmhao2005 i would appreciate i concrete answer

Comment: @DanielBank it feels that doing that in every component is a bit too much? I would like to do it in a higher component in the hierarchy